# Pairwise t.test multiple combinations in a Data Table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a **Data Table** with three columns: seller, product and price.

Example data:

```
      seller product price
  1:      A  banana    56
  2:      A   lemon    94
  3:      A  orange    84
  4:      A  banana    11
  5:      A   lemon    86
---                     
166:      C  orange   162
167:      C  banana   109
168:      C  orange    61
169:      C  banana   141
170:      C  orange    22
```

Code for the data

```
require (data.table)
DT <- data.table(seller = c(rep(c("A"),60),rep(c("B"),62),rep(c("C"),48)), product = c(rep(c("banana", "lemon", "orange"), 20), rep(c("banana", "lemon"), 31), rep(c("banana", "orange"), 24)), 
             price = c(56, 94, 84, 11, 86, 103, 151, 51, 117, 71, 63, 101, 45, 147, 135, 93, 26, 164, 90, 67, 12, 34, 14, 131, 92, 145, 48, 74, 62, 57, 20, 80, 113, 46, 88, 102, 134, 98, 137, 123, 169, 133, 146, 
                       160, 58, 42, 52, 158, 170, 2, 152, 10, 130, 30, 33, 144, 73, 41, 139, 107, 163, 9, 66, 81, 79, 127, 40, 165, 106, 161, 16, 1, 112, 70, 115, 138, 76, 105, 17, 118, 114, 121, 25, 39, 15, 155, 50, 166, 
                       100, 159, 5, 19, 29, 24, 64, 149, 120, 35, 119, 53, 21, 7, 72, 132, 154, 168, 156, 38, 3, 148, 69, 44, 6, 28, 140, 77, 104, 153, 59, 142, 116, 150, 97, 31, 91, 43, 47, 27, 143, 99, 37, 54, 49, 4, 111, 
                       32, 23, 85, 167, 136, 78, 129, 83, 124, 36, 96, 110, 13, 65, 108, 8, 18, 157, 87, 82, 60, 122, 89, 125, 68, 75, 126, 128, 55, 95, 162, 109, 61, 141, 22))
```

> I would like to perform a **pairwise T.test combination** between all sellers that sell the same products.

I would like to have an output as it is shown (hypotetical p.values for the example).

**Desire output:**

```
seller.x  seller.y  product  p.value
       A         B   banana     0.45
       A         B    lemon     0.87
       B         C   banana     0.03
       A         C   banana     0.23
       A         C   orange     0.01
```

Comment: `pairwise.t.test(df$price, interaction(df[,c("seller", "product")]))`

Comment: @mtoto This is only an example of the my real data. My real data are of millions of data, and hundreds of providers. We need to check significance between groups.

Comment: @Zelazny7 Your aproach was really interesting. However: * 1) I correct your syntaxis because the one that you suggested doesn´t work. The new sintaxis that I used is: pairwise.t.test(DT$price, interaction(DT[,seller],DT[,product])). 2) The output of the results from your sintaxis were inconrrect. I updated the example to have a more realistic data. Please check If I made any mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to group by `product`. Then, in your `j` parameter, you need to compute the combinations of `seller` for this `product` and get the `p.value` for the `t.test` of `price` between `seller.x` and `seller.y`:

```
DT[
  , {
    sellercomb <- data.table(t(combn(unique(seller), 2)))
    names(sellercomb) <- c("seller.x", "seller.y")
    sellercomb[
      , {
        data.table(p.value = t.test(price[seller == seller.x], price[seller == seller.y])$p.value)
      }
      , by = .(seller.x, seller.y)
    ]
  }
  , by = .(product)
]
```

The result for your data above looks like this:

```
   product seller.x seller.y   p.value
1:  banana        A        B 0.9384329
2:  banana        A        C 0.2413946
3:  banana        B        C 0.2154216
4:   lemon        A        B 0.7282811
5:  orange        A        C 0.0354320
```